# Overriding an existing Adapter

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I've been grappling with how to extend this adapter in my code:

```
public class InsectRecyclerAdapter<V extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder> extends
        RecyclerView.Adapter<InsectRecyclerAdapter.InsectHolder>
```

If I extend with the code below, I discovered that I wasn't able to bind my views and by extension the `ViewHolder`.

```
public class InsectAdapter extends 
InsectRecyclerAdapter<InsectRecyclerAdapter.InsectHolder> {

}
```

Any help is very much appreciated and many thanks.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why it isn't just `public class InsectAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<InsectRecyclerAdapter.InsectHolder>`?

Comment: Thanks EpicPandaForce, the instruction said i should extend the InsectRecyclerAdapter. I have never extended another adapter class before. I usually just use default (**public class InsentAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<InsectAdapter.InsectHolder>**) and implement the methods.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce... i modify my code to the to this **public class InsectAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<InsectRecyclerAdapter.InsectHolder>** and my question is do i need to recreate the ViewHolder in the new adapter?